# How do I increase the line spacing between these items?

Tags: line-spacing

I'm not sure how I can add line spacing of 1.2 or 1.5 between each of the items below

```
 \section{Coursework}
    Android Concurrency\\
    Web System Architecture\\
    Software Engineering\\
    Algorithms\\
    Design Patterns\\
    Database Management\\
    \sectionsep
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex.SX ! First, the example you have given is not complete, we require a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/90297). Second, you are abusing `\\ `, to get a new paragraph, simply add another linebreak (i.e. press enter twice) between each item. Third, you are looking for the vertical space commands `\medskip` `\bigskip` and `\vspace`

Comment: whenever `\\ ` is used outside of a table or an alignment, it is a sign that something is wrong. Isn't that some kind of list, which would be better marked up as `\item Android Concurrency \item Web System Architecture` ... It is impossible to tell (or answer the question) from such a small fragment

Comment: I am actually following this resume format, and this is the section coursework in this resume https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume. I'm sorry, I don't understand LaTex at all, just trying to understand enough to have my resume formatted.

Comment: Template confusion strikes again. Thanks templates :-(

Comment: Sometimes i read code and suddenly hear the voice of Ricky Gervais saying *Oh f\*ck me!*

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/exampleDeedyResume.md

Comment: @McFiddlyWiddly, after seeing your template, realising the `\\ ` was there originally, and seeing the template hell @Johannes_B posted. I have come to one final conclusion as to how to help you: DON'T USE THIS TEMPLATE. Check [this page](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume) out, it has simpler, better coded options...

Answer (score 2):

Use this command for 1.2:

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}‎‬
```

or use this command for 1.5:

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}‎‬
```

Comment: these would affect his entire document, I do believe he wanted spacing only between the items in this "list". But, again, it's hard to tell for sure...

Comment: @EladDen Well then go back to `1.0` or whatever. Look at the template, it really doesn't matter if you add a bit crappy code to the pile.

Answer (score 2):

You have several choices to get a bigger line spacing.

The important point is: Be aware that most (all?) CV templates are just rubbish.

[image: McFiddlyWiddly]

```
\section{Coursework}

\subsection{Graduate}

\begingroup
Advanced Machine Learning \\[5pt]
Open Source Software Engineering \\[5pt]
Advanced Interactive Graphics \\[5pt]
Compilers + Practicum \\[5pt]
Counting Ducks\\[5pt]
\setstretch{1.2}% needs package setspace
Advanced Machine Learning \\
Open Source Software Engineering \\
Advanced Interactive Graphics \\
Compilers + Practicum \\
Counting Ducks\\
\setlength{\parskip}{.5ex}
Advanced Machine Learning \par
Open Source Software Engineering \par
Advanced Interactive Graphics \par
Compilers + Practicum \par
Counting Ducks\par
\endgroup

\sectionspace % Some whitespace after the section
```

You could also use a `tabular` environment, or a list.